# How to copy values only using Sheets(Array()).Copy

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have the following code which copies worksheets to a new workbook. This currently copies the sheets with all the formulae etc. After this I loop though each worksheet in the resultant workbook to copy and paste values. Is there a way to create the worksheets with the values only the first time round?

```
Sheets(Array("EQ Spot Moves Valuation", _
                 "ZARi Swap Prll", _
                 "ZARi Bond Prll", _
                 "ZAR Swap PDH", _
                 "ZAR Bond PDH", _
                 "Grid Report EQ", _
                 "Valuations", _
                 "ZAR Bond Prll PDH", _
                 "Grid Report FX")).Copy
  ' ...snip

  For Each ws In exposureOutputWB.Sheets

  ' copy and past values on each sheet

  Next ws
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a difference to the Copy method if applied to worksheets or ranges. Only with ranges you can use the PasteSpecial [Format] later on, so you must copy ranges from the beginning, like in

```
Sub CopyAllAsValues()
Dim WO As Workbook, SO As Worksheet           ' old
Dim WN As Workbook, SN As Worksheet           ' new

    Set WO = ActiveWorkbook                   ' this is where we come from
    Set WN = Workbooks.Add                    ' the new sheet with only values

    For Each SO In WO.Worksheets
        Set SN = WN.Worksheets.Add            ' create new sheet
        SN.Name = SO.Name                     ' copy name
        SO.Cells.Copy                         ' copy all cells to clipboard
        SN.[A1].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    ' paste values at A1
        SN.[A1].PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats   ' paste formats as well at A1
    Next SO
End Sub
```

This code should illustrate the principle, it doesn't care for correct positioning of sheets (use `Before` or `After` parameters on `WorkSheets.Add`)and not for duplicate sheet names that may occur if one of the original sheet names match the default names in a newly created workbook on your system (usually Sheet1 .. Sheet3)

Hope that helps

good luck

Comment: Thanks - that's what I previously had almost verbatim before i found the sheets(array).copy..

Comment: just realised why I moved away the method your provided. All sheets from my source WB does not need to be copied, thus why I used `Sheets(Array("..")).Copy`

Comment: a bit overdue, but I ended up using a modified version of your solution with my existing approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the "Break Links" functionality. This will retain any calculations which refer only to other parts of the (new) workbook, but will replace all external cells with their values.

Manually from Edit -> Links -> Break links, or via VBA ([source](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=36183&s=26a41427c8cb3ef733f17574bed0b0fd&p=188522#post188522)):

```
Sub UseBreakLink()

Dim astrLinks As Variant

' Define variable as an Excel link type.
astrLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

' Break the first link in the active workbook.
For i = 1 To UBound(astrLinks)
   ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=astrLinks(i), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
Next i
End Sub
```